# Save data from form using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a chat box made in codeigniter that is working fine with static data, but i would like to connect it to database and make it dynamic

My requirement are:

> 1) when a user enters their name and email address under chatbox__credentials it needs to get saved in database
>
> 2) Using the email id, needs to display data in chatbox__body which is related to that email id
>
> 3) the entered email id also needs to be linked with the chatbox__message so that what ever message that user sends gets saved under their email id

Code on view page (index.php):

```
<div class="chatbox chatbox--tray chatbox--empty">
    <div class="chatbox__title">
        <h5><a href="#">Customer Service</a></h5>
        <button class="chatbox__title__tray">
            <span></span>
        </button>
        <button class="chatbox__title__close">
            <span>
                <svg viewBox="0 0 12 12" width="12px" height="12px">
                    <line stroke="#FFFFFF" x1="11.75" y1="0.25" x2="0.25" y2="11.75"></line>
                    <line stroke="#FFFFFF" x1="11.75" y1="11.75" x2="0.25" y2="0.25"></line>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="chatbox__body">
        <div class="chatbox__body__message chatbox__body__message--left">
            <img src="#" alt="Picture">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__body__message chatbox__body__message--right">
            <img src="#" alt="Picture">
            <p>Nulla vel turpis vulputate, tincidunt lectus sed, porta arcu.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__body__message chatbox__body__message--left">
            <img src="#" alt="Picture">
            <p>Curabitur consequat nisl suscipit odio porta, ornare blandit ante maximus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__body__message chatbox__body__message--right">
            <img src="#" alt="Picture">
            <p>Cras dui massa, placerat vel sapien sed, fringilla molestie justo.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__body__message chatbox__body__message--right">
            <img src="#" alt="Picture">
            <p>Praesent a gravida urna. Mauris eleifend, tellus ac fringilla imperdiet, odio dolor sodales libero, vel mattis elit mauris id erat. Phasellus leo nisi, convallis in euismod at, consectetur commodo urna.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form class="chatbox__credentials">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Enter Chat</button>
    </form>
    <textarea class="chatbox__message" placeholder="Write something interesting"></textarea>
</div>

(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $chatbox = $('.chatbox'),
            $chatboxTitle = $('.chatbox__title'),
            $chatboxTitleClose = $('.chatbox__title__close'),
            $chatboxCredentials = $('.chatbox__credentials');
        $chatboxTitle.on('click', function() {
            $chatbox.toggleClass('chatbox--tray');
        });
        $chatboxTitleClose.on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $chatbox.addClass('chatbox--closed');
        });
        $chatbox.on('transitionend', function() {
            if ($chatbox.hasClass('chatbox--closed')) $chatbox.remove();
        });
        $chatboxCredentials.on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $chatbox.removeClass('chatbox--empty');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**my chat box :**

```js
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $chatbox = $('.chatbox'),
            $chatboxTitle = $('.chatbox__title'),
            $chatboxTitleClose = $('.chatbox__title__close'),
            $chatboxCredentials = $('.chatbox__credentials');
        $chatboxTitle.on('click', function() {
            $chatbox.toggleClass('chatbox--tray');
        });
        $chatboxTitleClose.on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $chatbox.addClass('chatbox--closed');
        });
        $chatbox.on('transitionend', function() {
            if ($chatbox.hasClass('chatbox--closed')) $chatbox.remove();
        });
        $chatboxCredentials.on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $chatbox.removeClass('chatbox--empty');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.chatbox {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;

    -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
    transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.chatbox--tray {
    bottom: -350px;
}

.chatbox--closed {
    bottom: -400px;
}

.chatbox .form-control:focus {
    border-color: #1f2836;
}

.chatbox__title,
.chatbox__body {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.chatbox__title {
    min-height: 50px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #1f2836;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.chatbox__title h5 {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;

    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.chatbox__title h5 a {
    color: #fff;
    max-width: 195px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.chatbox__title h5:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    border-radius: 6px;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.chatbox__title__tray,
.chatbox__title__close {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    outline: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
}

.chatbox__title__tray:hover,
.chatbox__title__close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.chatbox__title__tray span {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff
}

.chatbox__title__close svg {
    vertical-align: middle;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-width: 1.2px;
}

.chatbox__body,
.chatbox__credentials {
    padding: 15px;
    border-top: 0;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;

    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.chatbox__credentials {
    display: none;
}

.chatbox__credentials .form-control {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.chatbox__body {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.chatbox__body__message {
    position: relative;
}

.chatbox__body__message p {
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
}

.chatbox__body__message img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #fcfcfc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
}

.chatbox__body__message--left p {
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}

.chatbox__body__message--left img {
    left: -5px;
}

.chatbox__body__message--right p {
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-align: right;
}

.chatbox__body__message--right img {
    right: -5px;
}

.chatbox__message {
    padding: 15px;
    min-height: 50px;
    outline: 0;
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #fefefe;
}

.chatbox--empty {
    height: 262px;
}

.chatbox--empty.chatbox--tray {
    bottom: -212px;
}

.chatbox--empty.chatbox--closed {
    bottom: -262px;
}

.chatbox--empty .chatbox__body,
.chatbox--empty .chatbox__message {
    display: none;
}

.chatbox--empty .chatbox__credentials {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  

<div class="chatbox chatbox--tray chatbox--empty">
    <div class="chatbox__title">
        <h5><a href="#">Customer Service</a></h5>
        <button class="chatbox__title__tray">
            <span></span>
        </button>
        <button class="chatbox__title__close">
            <span>
                <svg viewBox="0 0 12 12" width="12px" height="12px">
                    <line stroke="#FFFFFF" x1="11.75" y1="0.25" x2="0.25" y2="11.75"></line>
                    <line stroke="#FFFFFF" x1="11.75" y1="11.75" x2="0.25" y2="0.25"></line>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="chatbox__body">
        <div class="chatbox__body__message chatbox__body__message--left">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brad_frost/128.jpg" alt="Picture">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__body__message chatbox__body__message--right">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/arashmil/128.jpg" alt="Picture">
            <p>Nulla vel turpis vulputate, tincidunt lectus sed, porta arcu.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__body__message chatbox__body__message--left">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brad_frost/128.jpg" alt="Picture">
            <p>Curabitur consequat nisl suscipit odio porta, ornare blandit ante maximus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__body__message chatbox__body__message--right">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/arashmil/128.jpg" alt="Picture">
            <p>Cras dui massa, placerat vel sapien sed, fringilla molestie justo.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__body__message chatbox__body__message--right">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/arashmil/128.jpg" alt="Picture">
            <p>Praesent a gravida urna. Mauris eleifend, tellus ac fringilla imperdiet, odio dolor sodales libero, vel mattis elit mauris id erat. Phasellus leo nisi, convallis in euismod at, consectetur commodo urna.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form class="chatbox__credentials">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Enter Chat</button>
    </form>
    <textarea class="chatbox__message" placeholder="Write something interesting"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need AJAX to proper and elegant functioning of your routine.

I didn't see a word into there. You already considered and are avoiding or just don't know?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Comment: @Carlos Alexandre i tried using ajax but if i am using it then it is hindering the functionality of chat box

Comment: you have to use ajax+polling or nodejs+sockets. if you want to persist chat data in database